# How does regex capturing work in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

Here is an example:

```
object RegexTest {
  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = "Enjoy this apple 3.14 times"
    val pattern = """.* apple ([\d.]+) times""".r
    val pattern(amountText) = input
    val amount = amountText.toDouble
    println(amount)
  }
}
```

I understand what this does, but how does `val pattern(amountText) = input` actually work? It looks very weird to me.

Answer (score 4):

What that line is doing is calling [`Regex.unapplySeq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@unapplySeq(s:CharSequence):Option[List[String]]) (which is also called an [*extractor*](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112)) to deconstruct `input` into a list of captured groups, and then bind each group to a new variable. In this particular scenario, only one group is expected to be captured and bound to the value `amountText`.

Validation aside, this is kinda what's going on behind the scenes:

```
val capturedGroups = pattern.unapplySeq(input)
val amountText = capturedGroups(0)

// And this:
val pattern(a, b, c) = input

// Would be equivalent to this:
val capturedGroups = pattern.unapplySeq(input)
val a = capturedGroups(0)
val b = capturedGroups(1)
val c = capturedGroups(2)
```

It is very similar in essence to extracting tuples:

```
val (a, b) = (2, 3)
```

Or even pattern matching:

```
(2,3) match {
  case (a, b) => 
}
```

In both of these cases, `Tuple.unapply` is being called.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at this page : http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html. It is the official tutorial regarding *extractors* which this the pattern you are looking for.

I find that looking at the source makes it clear how it works : https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/matching/Regex.scala#L243

Then, note that your code `val pattern(amountText) = input` is perfectly working, but, you must be sure about the input and be sure that there is a match with the regex.

Otherwise, I recommend you to write it this way :

`input match {
  case pattern(amountText) => ...
  case _ => ...
}`