# What does `val (_, x) = ...` mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand this scala code (modified from [here](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-relay/blob/f042f43231a6e1a7ba0aeb09f9272126a5b52110/src/test/scala/sangria/relay/starWars/StarWarsSchema.scala#L126)):

```
val ConnectionDefinition(_, eventConnection) =
  Connection.definition[EventRepo, Connection, Event]("Event", EventType)
```

This is inside an `object`. It seems like it's using the return value of the function `Connection.definition[EventRepo, Connection, Event]("Event", EventType)` to instantiate a case class, unpacking the return values(?), but:

1. Why is it just `val ConnectionDefinition(_, eventConnection)`? Is this some sort of anonymous value or something since there's no identifier (e.g. `val myVal = ...`.
2. Why even bother to give any of the arguments to ConnectionDefinition names (i.e. `eventConnection`)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32054280/857807

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The val that is being defined is `eventConnection`, which is the second parameter in the deconstruction (`unapply`) of the `ConnectionDefinition` instance returned by the call to `Connection.definition`. Now `eventConnection` will be available to the rest of the code (the rest of the `ConnectionDefinition` instance returned will not be, but presumeably isn't required).

Comment: Maybe you should mention explicitly that `val` declarations are simply standard pattern matching. (Well, a subset of pattern matching anyway.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, that might have been better wording - thanks for providing it!

Comment: What is the `_` on the left hand side? A throwaway?

Comment: @Paul Yes. That deconstructed parameter could also have been given a name, and would then be accessible under that name in the following code, but was presumably not required, so the place-holder `_` was used instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a destructuring assignment with the first value ignored.

`ConnectionDefinition` is a case class with two values. A case class automatically implements an extractor (the `unapply` method) which is called when you pattern match.

Here are some things you can do with this language feature:

```
case class ConnectionDefinition(edgeType: ObjectType, connectionType: ObjectType)
object Connection {
  def definition(): ConnectionDefinition = ???
}

// basic assignment:
val conn = Connection.definition()
val conn: ConnectionDefinition = Connection.definition()

// extract the two values from the case class:
val ConnectionDefinition(edgeType, connType) = Connection.definition()
val ConnectionDefinition(edgeType: ObjectType, connType: ObjectType) = Connection.definition()

// extract only one value and ignore the other:
val ConnectionDefinition(edgeType, _) = Connection.definition()
val ConnectionDefinition(_, connType) = Connection.definition()

// extract both values AND still keep a reference to the whole ConnectionDefinition
val conn @ ConnectionDefinition(edgeType, connType) = Connection.definition()
```